# How to simplify this JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to combine these two functions to one?

I have tried to use multiple selectors in one function but got no working results.

I'm not familiar with vanilla JS. 
Thank you in advance!

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

   var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('viewangle');
   var paragraph = document.querySelector('#closedview');

    for(var i=0;i< radioButtons.length;i++)
    {
        var elem = radioButtons[i];
        elem.addEventListener('change',function(e){
            console.log(paragraph);
            if(paragraph.className)
                paragraph.className = this.value;
            else
                paragraph.classList.add(this.value);
        }
        ,false);

    }
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

   var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('viewangle');
   var paragraph = document.querySelector('#openedview');

    for(var i=0;i< radioButtons.length;i++)
    {
        var elem = radioButtons[i];
        elem.addEventListener('change',function(e){
            console.log(paragraph);
            if(paragraph.className)
                paragraph.className = this.value;
            else
                paragraph.classList.add(this.value);
        }
        ,false);

    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? You've tagged it but not used at all in code

Comment: You should really rename the question, this is not following stack overflow rules at all.

Comment: It seems you're just looking for an appropriate selector, which would be `document.querySelectorAll('#openedview, #closedview')` which will return a collection of 0 to 2 elements which you can iterate over using a for loop (like an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the two paragraph 1 (closedview) and 2 (openedview):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("viewangle");
    var paragraph1 = document.getElementById("closedview");
    var paragraph2 = document.getElementById("openedview");
    for(var i=0;i< radioButtons.length;i++){
        var elem = radioButtons[i];
        elem.addEventListener('change',function(e){
            console.log(paragraph1);
            console.log(paragraph2);
            if(paragraph1.className){ paragraph1.className = this.value; }else{ paragraph1.classList.add(this.value); }
            if(paragraph2.className){ paragraph2.className = this.value; }else{ paragraph2.classList.add(this.value); }
        }
        ,false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Within the context of the OP, `paragraph1.className = this.value` and `paragraph1.classList.add(this.value)` will do exactly the same thing. If *paragraph1.className* has any value (i.e. is a string of 1 or more characters), it will be replaced by *this.value*, and if it has no value (i.e. returns an empty string), then *this.value* will be added to the empty class list. So either way, it ends up being *this.value*. Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Put the plain stuff in one function, and pass differences as parameter, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  myFunction('#closedview');
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  myFunction('#openedview');
});

function myFunction(viewId) {
  var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('viewangle');
  var paragraph = document.querySelector(viewId);

  for(var i=0;i< radioButtons.length;i++) {
    var elem = radioButtons[i];
    elem.addEventListener('change',function(e){
      console.log(paragraph);
      if(paragraph.className) {
        paragraph.className = this.value;
      } else {
          paragraph.classList.add(this.value);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Or combine with @RobG's answer: pass the result of document.querySelector() to myFunction().

PS: @Federico's answer is actually cleaner and better: you only need to add only 1 eventlistener.. to DOMContentLoaded